# Could not resolve type id 'size-rotating-file' into a subtype of [simple type, class io.dropwizard.logging.AppenderFactory]

Tags: maven, logging, pom.xml, dropwizard

I am getting this error while using logging appenders in my Dropwizard project.
Could not resolve type id 'size-rotating-file' into a subtype of [simple type, class io.dropwizard.logging.AppenderFactory]
 at [Source: N/A; line: -1, column: -1] (through reference chain: com.flipkart.apl.config.EuropaConfiguration["logging"]->io.dropwizard.logging.LoggingFactory["appenders"])

I found similar issues in some older post but they were using maven-shaded-plugin which I am not using in my pom.xml. Here is my pom.xml dependencies.

```
<dependencies>
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
  <artifactId>dropwizard-core</artifactId>
  <version>0.7.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
  <artifactId>dropwizard-hibernate</artifactId>
  <version>0.7.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
  <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
  <version>0.8.2.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
  <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
  <version>1.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>com.restbus</groupId>
  <artifactId>dropwizard-hibernate-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.1.1</version>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>


<dependency>
  <groupId>fk.sp.common</groupId>
  <artifactId>event-handler</artifactId>
  <version>1.7.18</version>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>


<dependency>
  <groupId>fk.sp.common</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-jpa</artifactId>
  <version>1.7.18</version>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>fk.sp.common</groupId>
  <artifactId>common-extensions</artifactId>
  <version>1.7.18</version>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>fk.sp.common</groupId>
  <artifactId>restbus-sender</artifactId>
  <version>1.7.18</version>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>com.restbus</groupId>
  <artifactId>restbus-client</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.3</version>
  <exclusions>
    <!-- In order to use the log4j-over-slf4j module, we must ensure
    that log4j and slf4j-log4j12 are not in the classpath -->
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <!-- excluding org.jboss.netty because maven can't detect it's collision with io.netty -->
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>org.jboss.netty</groupId>
      <artifactId>netty</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>mysql</groupId>
  <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
  <version>5.1.28</version>
  <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>3.8.1</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

org.codehaus.mojo
        exec-maven-plugin
        1.2.1
        
          com.flipkart.apl.Europa
          
            server
            europa.yml

```
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <archive>
        <manifest>
          <mainClass>com.flipkart.apl.Europa</mainClass>
        </manifest>
      </archive>
      <descriptorRefs>
        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
      </descriptorRefs>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>

  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1</version>
    <configuration>
      <source>1.7</source>
      <target>1.7</target>
      <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

**Edited**

```
logging:  
    level: INFO  
    loggers:  
      com.flipkart.apl: INFO  
appenders:    
    - type: size-rotating-file  
      threshold: ALL  
      logFormat: "%-5p [%d{ISO8601}] [%X{reqId} %X{txnId}] %replace(%c: %m){'\n', '\n '}%n%replace(%ex){'(?m)^(.)',' $1'}%nopex"  
      currentLogFilename: /var/log/fk-apl-europa/europa.log  
      archivedLogFilenamePattern: /var/log/fk-apl-europa/europa%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH}-%i.log.gz  
      maxFileSize: "100mb"  
      maxArchivedDataSize: "1gb"  
  - type: console  
      logFormat: "%-5p [%d{ISO8601}] [%X{reqId} %X{txnId}] %c: %m\n%ex"  
      threshold: INFO
```

Comment: Hi - this sounds more like you are using the wrong property? I do not have 0.7.1 locally at the moment, but my appender factory only has the property: maxFileSize 

Can you edit your post with your yaml configuration?

Comment: edited with yaml configuration I am using.

Comment: Thanks - did you define the size-rotating-file anywhere? Where did you get this appender from? Can you point me to documentation? I can not see it in the 0.7.x release of dropwizard which would explain why you are not able to configure that. The normal file appender in DW allows rotating files and file restriction, but its service name is simply "file". That points towards you using a custom appender which I will have to look at  :)

Comment: we have created our customized appender which is returned for key "size-rotating-file" . I used "file" also but same error,
Could not resolve type id 'file' into a subtype of [simple type, class io.dropwizard.logging.AppenderFactory]

I think there is some runtime exception while resolving appender type, does it have anything related to maven-assembly-plugin??

Comment: It might be. When you assemble your project, can you unpack and make sure that all classes you need (and resources since the appenders need to be discovered) are available on the classpath?

Comment: I checked this, All classes are there in the classpath, still facing this issue :(

Comment: The way you are running it, doesn't that ignore the build file anyway and run it from within maven? Do you have a configuration for the exec plugin? You could try and modify your code to print all classpath entries on startup (before loading the yaml) to see what is actually on the classpath